# Send json data as parameter via $.Ajax

Tags: jquery, json, jsonp

I want to send to the backend a json string as one parameter and also other parameters. I am expecting to receive results as jsonp.

the parameters are

```
$param1 = '                          {
                              "MetaData": [
                                    {"Index": "0", "Name": "COLUMN_NAME"},
                                    {"Index": "1", "Name": "VALUE"},
                                    {"Index": "2", "Name": "VALUE_CHANGED"}
                                            ],
                              "Data": [
                                    ["ORDER_NO","*2733","f"],
                                    ["DISCOUNT_NO","1","f"],
                                    ["DISCOUNT_TYPE","S1","f"],
                                    ["DISCOUNT","11.4","t"],

                                            ]
                            } ';
```

how should I write the syntax in js and how should I receive it from the php side? when I try to use it like below it doesn't work.

```
$.ajax({

    url: 'http://... myfile.php',
    data: {PARAMETER1: $param1, PARAMETER2: $param2}
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    error: function() { alert('Failed!'); }

}).done(function( data ) {
                            $.each(data, function(k,v) {
                               alert( "key: "+k+"  val:" + v);
                            })
                         });
```

Comment: why you want to sent data to server as json format ?

Comment: Why are you sending data in this way?  Why not just make `$param1` an object, and let it be decoded into `$_GET` automatically?

Comment: Msi Saurovh I need to send multiple rows to the server side. so it must be an array or json or similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Javascript code looks OK to me. On the PHP side, it would be:

```
$param1 = json_decode($_GET['PARAMETER1'], true);
```

Then you can access `$param1['MetaData'][$i]['Index']`, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

you are sending object containing two strings

at your php code you should decode them to json using json_decode

it depends on your back end code / framework ... just read them then decode them

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){


        param1 = ' { "MetaData": [ {"Index": "0", "Name": "COLUMN_NAME"},
        {"Index": "1", "Name":"VALUE"}, {"Index": "2", "Name": "VALUE_CHANGED"} ], 
        "Data": [ ["ORDER_NO","*2733","f"], ["DISCOUNT_NO","1","f"],
        ["DISCOUNT_TYPE","S1","f"],
        ["DISCOUNT","11.4","t"], ] } '; 
         param2 ='2';

         $.ajax({ url: 'ajaxresponse.jsp', 
         type: 'POST',
         data:'{"PARAMETER1":'+ param1+',"PARAMETER2":'+ param2+'}',
         contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
         dataType: 'json',
         async: false, 
         success: function(msg) { alert(msg); } });

    });
```